# jquery upload validation won't delete msg when valid how to fix this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, upload

At first I thought it was something I added but then I used a blank page and did it super simple and realised that let's say if I have upload field required. After file is selected the error message will not be removed unless submit is selected.

as for inputs, errors does remove itself

how can this be fixed?

Below is a simple test

```
<form action="" id="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="file" name="aaaupload">
    <input type="submit" value="sub">
</form>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#myForm').validate({
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true
            },
            aaaupload: {
                required: true
            }
        }
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/r0nemr7n/ ? but when you click again error goes

Comment: @Novice you have to click somewhere in the browser, it's not like after file is selected then it's gone.  Not sure if you get what I mean

Comment: No I got what you meant you need to call `valid()` yourself on `change` of file input like this http://jsfiddle.net/Ljprpdvm/. But yes you have a nice point I also wonder why doesn't validation plugin call `valid()` automatically when file input changes.